# How to deleted words from class

Tags: class, xpath

I study xpath alone and I have question about how to delete word from class. I am newbie so be patient.

I have functional xpath

```
"//*[@id="article"]//*[@class="submeta__keywords"]//a/@data-link-name"
```

my result is:

```
"keyword: sport/nfl"
```

I tried `"[contains(@class="submeta__keywords, 'delete_link')]"` but it doesn't work.

Also I want to delete the `"keyword"` from xpath, any advice about it?

Comment: please add more codes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your request, but if you want to strip "keyword" from the output you can use :

```
substring-after(//*[@id="article"]//*[@class="submeta__keywords"]//a/@data-link-name,"keyword: ")
```

or

```
substring(//*[@id="article"]//*[@class="submeta__keywords"]//a/@data-link-name,9,100)
```

Output : `sport/nfl`

In the first expression, we only keep the text after the word "keyword". In the second one we define a starting position and the length of the string to extract.

If you want to exclude "keyword" from your XPath expression (i.e. write it differently), you can go with :

```
//*[@id="article"]//*[starts-with(@class,"submeta__")]//a/@data-link-name
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you

I think this is right but our company system doesnt work with substring-after at the beginning of the code is it way to include substring-after elsewhere?

```
substring-after(//*[@id="article"]//*[@class="submeta__keywords"]//a/@data-link-name,"keyword: ")
```

Comment: Hi. Please respond in comments for better readability. In your case,you can't use `susbtring-after` elsewhere. Can you retrieve the content of `@class` with XPath and strip the unnecessary part with any programming language (R, Python, PHP,...) ? Your company system can't use regex ?